# JSP page is not display data sent from Controller class

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

````
```


      package
````

com.springmvcnew;

```
        import
```

org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

```
       @Controller
     public class HomeController {
      @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String home(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Home page is with model calling!!!!");
        model.addAttribute("name","Khsin alvin");
        return "index";

        }

     @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String about() {
        System.out.println("About page is calling!!!!");
        return "about";

        }
      }
   My Jsp Page is here
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Welcome to the Home page of MVC Project</h1>

  <%
  String Myname = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
   %>
  <h2>My name is <% Myname %> </h2>
  </body>
   </html>
```

````
            this is simple mvc 
      spring project want to send 
   data from controller to display 
   in jsp      
          but at jsp it gives 
    error of multiple annotation 
    when i retrieve value in <% %> 
    tag.
          i could't understand 
    what is error. i am new in 
    this field.so that i can do 
    this easily.  
           i am using eclips for 
    this project.

    

  

    ```
   

          package com.springmvcnew;
    
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.ui.Model;
           import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    
           @Controller
         public class HomeController {
          @RequestMapping("/home")
            public String home(Model model) {
            System.out.println("Home page is with model calling!!!!");
            model.addAttribute("name","Khsin alvin");
            return "index";
    
            }
    
         @RequestMapping("/about")
        public String about() {
            System.out.println("About page is calling!!!!");
            return "about";
    
            }
          }
       My Jsp Page is here
       <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
       <title>Insert title here</title>
       </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Welcome to the Home page of MVC Project</h1>
    
      <%
      String Myname = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
       %>
      <h2>My name is <% Myname %> </h2>
      </body>
       </html>
````

```
        this is simple mvc 
  spring project want to send
```

data from controller to display
in jsp
but at jsp it gives
error of multiple annotation
when i retrieve value in <% %>
tag.
i could't understand
what is error. i am new in
this field.so that i can do
this easily.
i am using eclips for
this project.